# Public WIFI does not connect

Tags: tor-browser-bundle

Is it common for Tor browser not to connect when using public WIFI? For example a Starbucks WIFI that requires you to "accept" their access agreement.

Comment: Short answer, yes.

Comment: I have this problem also, except after accepting from the un-safe browser. Tor cannot connect to any websites. The Unsafe browser still works. Is this something to do with MAC spoofing?

Comment: I found this doesn't work, using either Windows or Linux, even when using an array of bridges. Repeat attempts to access the net via Tor, after logging on a public wifi network using an unsafe browser, consistently fail. Sadly, what's worse is the lack of access to Tor settings in the standard implementations and in Tails, which only allow bridge configuration until the browser and Vidalia are actually running: Tor itself and the browser are seperate affairs, and neither can be accessed until Tor is established. If Tor fails, even rebooting it manually after disconnecting and reconnecting to t

Answer (score 2):

Yes. You need your browser to connect to local network and Accept, before you (that is, Tor) is allowed to make any connection to Internet.

Proper sequence would be:

1. Connect to cafe's network from your OS
2. Open non-Tor browser
3. Accept terms, introduce login, etc.
4. Close non-Tor browser (unless it specifically says not to close the connection window/tab)
5. Open Tor